# WCF - how to check if the request was from MetaDataExchange

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a WCF service that is used by a remote client. For security reasons, the client is set up to send a header with some User data. On the service side, I have a class that implements **IDispatchMessageInspector**.

Inside the class (in the **AfterReceiveRequest** method) I am checking on each received message, if the user data is valid - if it is not valid(or missing) an exception is thrown. This, however, is also triggered when a client tries to reference or update the service - the service treats it as a regular soap message. And as this message does not contain the necessary headers, it fails.

I have done the following hack to go around this issue:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        MessageHeaders headers = request.Headers;
        int index = headers.FindHeader(HEADER_NAME, NAMESPACE);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            // skip verification and log-in if the caller is the MetadataExchangeService
            if (headers.To.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("mex"))
            {
                return null;
            }

            throw new SecurityException(string.Format("WCF message contains no header with name '{0}' and namespace '{1}'.", HEADER_NAME, NAMESPACE));
        }

   // rest of code.....
}
```

So my question is - is there a smarter way to check if the call originates from Mex? Or maybe the **AfterReceiveRequest** is not the best place to do this userverification?

Comment: Does this not introduce a security hole in your service? It would seem to avoid security check I only have to put "mex" on the end of my call.

Comment: yes, this is why I'm looking for a smarter way to do it :)